# Wrong NTP date response Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, ntp

I'm using [Kronos](https://github.com/lyft/Kronos) to get date from NTP Servers, the problem is that the returned date is wrong.

**Example:**
The time in my country is 2019-2-2 20:22:05 +0000 
but what i get is 2019-2-2 22:22:05 +0000

I think It's about the timezone, but i couldn't reach it

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some code?  I checked using the unit tests that are in Kronos and it returns the correct UTC time.

Comment: I didn't do match I just used this block of code to test it before: ` Clock.sync { date, offset in
            print(date)
        }`

Comment: Are you -2 hours from UTC? Are you sure the local time isn't 019-2-2 20:22:05 -0200?  The framework is working for me.  You should edit your question to show the output of your test. ie `print (date)` followed by `print(Date())` - assuming your device's local time is accurate. What output do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some code to make it right

```
Clock.sync { date, offset in
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar.current
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

        let dt = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

        print(dt)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob for your comment, but it worked in both ways